# Java and Axis cameras

Tags: java, applet, vapix

I am writing a Java applet to display live images from Axis cameras.
Is there a good library I can download that abstracts camera image fetching using VAPIX?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to display video, motion JPEG or still JPEGs?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that - but I want to see the video feed from the camera.

This thread provided the necessary Java code:
http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=494920&forumID=28

Comment: Nice work Warlax. As a friendly reminder, can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the axis media player SDK once installed check the install directory and you will have sample code that you can use and I belive one is for java.